# AFNetworking completion block not called?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking-2

I have a chunk of code here, which basically calls my servlet (which it did), and then return the result. However, if I added the sync/blocking portion in (refer to `if(isSync)`), the completion block doesn't get called and the whole app hangs there in `dispatch_group_wait`. This code is called from the main thread if it makes any difference.

```
// ...More code here


if(isSync)
{
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
}

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:REQ];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSDictionary *result = responseObject;
    NSLog(@"JSON responseObject: %@ ", result);
    if(isSync)
    {
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    if(isSync)
    {
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }
}];
[op start];
if(isSync)
{
    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It was  dumb mistake, after coming back to it in a while I found the problem -.-. I wasn't using the group async at all x.x

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and took me a while to realise that the operation runs the blocks in a particular queue (default queue).

That said, assuming you are running your code in the same queue, if you block/stop the running code using `dispatch_group_wait` the success and failure blocks will never run. To fix that you can add the completion queue and group to the operation, making the operation to run the block in a different queue. The code below is in swift, not sure if it is the same in objective-c.

```
 operation.completionQueue = queue;
 operation.completionGroup = postGroup;
```